# Log transformed data in GAM, how to plot response?

Tags: gam, mgcv

I used log-transformed data (dependent varibale=count) in my generalised additive model (using mgcv) and tried to plot the response by using "trans=plogis" as for logistic GAMs but the results don't seem right. Am I forgetting something here? When I used linear models for my data first, I plotted the least-square means. Any idea how I could plot the output of my GAMs in a more interpretable way other than on the log scale?

Cheers

Comment: I'll add to my post that back-transforming from the log-odds space of logistic regression to the probability space-constrained between 0 and 1 - is done with plogis. If that is what you need to do, edit your post and I'll edit my response.

Comment: Perhaps a more pertinent question is why are you transforming your count data and then fitting a GAM? You could fit a GAM with a Poisson, negative binomial family for example and you wouldn't need to do the transformation (you would need to back transform still; but at least you'd be modeling the thing of interest – expected value of Y not of log(Y).)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I am modelling count data of observed species during specific lunar illumination (predictor) and did linear models first but then realised that there might be a non-linear relationship -- which there is. I used fitdistr() to see which distribution fits the data best and that is log, so that's why I transformed my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a logistic regression for count data? Logistic regression is normally a binary variable or a proportion of binary outcomes.

That being said, the real question here is that you want to backtransform a variable that was fit on the log scale back to the original scale for plotting. That can be easily done using the `itsadug` package. I've simulated some silly data here just to show the code required.

With itsadug, you can visually inspect many aspects of GAM models. I'd encourage you to look at this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsadug/vignettes/inspect.html

The transform argument of `plot_smooth()` can also be used with custom functions written in R. This can be useful if you have both centred and logged a dependent variable.

```
library(mgcv)
library(itsadug)

# Setting seed so it's reproducible
set.seed(123)

# Generating 50 samples from a uniform distribution
x <- runif(50, min = 20, max = 50)

# Taking the sin of x to create a dependent variable
y <- sin(x) 

# Binding them to a dataframe
d <- data.frame(x, y)

# Logging the dependent variable after adding a constant to prevent negative values
d$log_y <- log(d$y + 1)

# Fitting a GAM to the transformed dependent variable
model_fit <- gam(log_y ~ s(x),
                 data = d)

# Using the plot_smooth function from itsadug to backtransform to original y scale
plot_smooth(model_fit,
            view = "x",
            transform = exp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the trans function for back-transforming as :`trans = function(x){exp(coef(gam)[1]+x)}`, where `gam` is your fitted model, and `coef(gam)[1]` is the intercept.